# birt-viewer-osgi Frameset Error unbale to run sample test.rptdesign file

Tags: birt

I have configured `Tomcat server` on `rocky Linux` and copied `birt` runtime into `/opt/tomcat/webapps/` folder. The issue is that `birt` home page is working fine but when I try to fetch example report it does not fetch the sample report and displays an error like:

The requested resource [/birt-viewer-osgi/] is not available.

I have checked and verified permission on webapps folder and all files and folder are belong to tomcat user.

I have downgraded the `Tomcat version` from `10` to `9` because on of the person shared me this information that the key difference between Tomcat 10 and Tomcat 9 is that `Tomcat 10` is only compatible with the new **jakarta** namespace and `Tomcat 9` is compatible with the old **javax** namespace.

`BIRT` still relays on the old **javax** namespace, hence it is incompatible with `Tomcat 10`. You should use `Tomcat 9` instead, hopefully, that will solve your problem.

I did it in the same way and after that, the nature of the error changed it still displays a `404` error but status is showing different messages like

[404-Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqgC7.png)

[Tomcat server status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytMTY.png)

[BIRT error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXYzp.png)

Today I downloaded old version of `BIRT birt-runtime-4_2_2` but encountered the same issue that was coming on new versions.

even permission are set exactly with tomcat user

[permissions-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ9WO.png) [permissions-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEMlC.png)

Comment: can someone give a resolution regarding this issue I have searching for this for a month but have had no luck resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved.

a guy who suggested to I downgrade from Tomcat 10 to 9 because of a different namespace.

The problematic thing was that I was using an old Birt version that was not compatible with the Java version. so I downloaded the latest version of BIRT Viewer runtime and copied it into web apps folder it is working fine and homepage is displaying properly on the browser and sample reports too which already exist in the folder.